# how to preseed snap packages?

Tags: chroot, preseed, snap

I am trying to create a custom ubuntu image, but can only do it from chroot because of cubic limitations. In that custom image, however, I want to include snaps, which require snapd to be running. Unfortunatly, because of chroot limitations, I can't install any snaps. I am now turning to preseeding. Unfortunatly, this is out of my expertise and I couldn't find any guides online. Is there any one here that can give me instructions on how to preseed snaps?

Comment: I don't think preseeds support it. You'd need cloud-init: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FoundationsTeam/AutomatedServerInstalls#The_structure_of_an_autoinstall_config

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track... I think there could be some potential in cloud-init for what I am trying to do.